# Can't run Firebase cli commands after npm install -g. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry. Module not found

Tags: node.js, firebase-tools

I installed firebase-tools with

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

However when I do firebase init or other cli commands I get an error.

```
firebase
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:444
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\12155\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:436:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:678:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\12155\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\pac-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:39:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\12155\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\socks-proxy-agent\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'socks-proxy-agent'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Issue started when I ran npm install -g firebase-tools when I already had it installed, prior to that firebase cli was working. However uninstalling and reinstalling didn't work. Even tried deleting the firebase cli folder, but nothing works. Also I saw some other posts online about deleting the node modules folder, but I am just trying to use the firebase cli there is no node modules folder to delete.

I encountered this issue before and fixed it, but I am not sure how it was resolved as it was too long ago. I am on a windows computer.

Edit: Warnings that I got when I installed firebase tools

```
>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\12155\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js.DELETE.12e9f100a7307238826cd2a1e93e2ca4'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\12155\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\dist\index.js'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\12155\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\dist\index.js'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\12155\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\pac-resolver\dist\index.js.DELETE.ceb31c0dc58c707624f6211476b72eb4'
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\12155\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\get-uri\dist\index.js.DELETE.006f3dd7d637272339a132b0d45dcb9d'
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

Comment: Uninstalled node and reinstalled fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reinstalling node somehow fixed the issue. Neeeded to reinstall a few times.

Comment: Hi I have exact same issue as you. Can you let me know which version of node you had installed before problem, and what version did you reinstall with? I'm on 18.8.0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I don't recall exactly, but I believe I had node version Node.js v18.16.0 before and after. I can't be sure though it has been a while.

Comment: managed to solve it by clearing cache and then needed to install it 2 times for it to work.